# userContentController is never called

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I am trying to use WKScriptMessageHandler in my iOS app to catch some messages from javascript.

I am doing this in function in javascript:

```
var dict = { "favourite": "true", "id": "id" };
webkit.messageHandlers.callbackHandler.postMessage(dict);
```

And in iOS I set up my WebView like this:

```
let contentController = WKUserContentController()
contentController.add(self, name: "callbackHandler")
let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
config.userContentController = contentController
webview = WKWebView( frame: view.bounds, configuration: config)
view.insertSubview(webview!, at: 1)
```

in loadView() method.

My ViewController implements WKScriptMessageHandler and its method userContentController like this:

```
func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
    print("in")
}
```

but whatever I try, method userContentController is never called.

Answer (score 0):

conform the class to the protocol "WKScriptMessageHandler"

```
class MyClass : WKScriptMessageHandler{

}
```